# div and image within div acting seperate

Tags: html, css

Hey guys i'm having an issue with my div and image (image is on the same div) the problem is that the top of the div where my header (h1) is and the image on the div respond independently.

I want everything to happen regardless of where I hover on the div but at the moment if i hover on the header the image doesn't change and vice versa. So I was wondering how to make both my Div and image activate their "hover" instructions when either is hovered on.

currently the image is getting the shadow from the div hover (but still only when the image is hovered on) so i just want this and the image to get darker even if the header is hovered on.

not really sure what code would be helpful here so if you want anything else just ask. Thanks in advance.

html:

```
<a href="#">
 <div id = "item1">
  <div id = "header">
   <h1>Results</h1>
  </div> <!-- header  end -->
   <img src="Olympics1.png" alt = "olympic pic">
 </div><!-- item 1 -->
</a>
```

css:

```
.mainBody #item1 :hover
{
background-color: #50B847;
color: #ffffff;
box-shadow: 10px 10px 20px 1px #ccc;
}

#item1  img:hover
{
 -webkit-filter: brightness(35%);
}
```

Comment: Can you please toss "Olympics1.png" on a server? Need a size reference.

Comment: okay so there's a div that contains a heading and image inside it. On "item 1" hover to want to change the background of heading and brightness of image. Is that so?

Comment: yep that's right :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this-

```
.mainBody #item1:hover
{
background-color: #50B847;
color: #ffffff;
box-shadow: 10px 10px 20px 1px #ccc;
}
.mainBody #item1:hover img
{
  -webkit-filter: brightness(35%);
}
```

Edits-
space removed from .mainBody #item1 :hover
modified #item1  img:hover

Removing space makes the header part work and your image changed when the mouse hovered over it, but in the modified one, hover over 'item1' and it changes how the header and image looks.

Comment: Hey sorry for the late response, this is exactly what I was after, thanks!